# Условия if/elif. как прервать выполнение условий, когда одно уже подошло?

Tags: python-3.x

Как сделать так, чтобы после выполнения одного условия программа не проверяла другие?

Comment: В чем именно проблема? Приведите пример когда такого прерывания не происходит

Comment: Выбирайте любое понравившееся: return/break/continue/exit/quit/raise. А лучше добавьте ваш код с проблемой

Comment: Комбинация if/elif именно этим и занимается, не? Вопрос непонятен